# SP Hosted-AddIn - Pass body parameter to SP.WebRequestInfo() object

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app, api

I want to pass body parameters to my post request, how to do this? In msdn [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179895.aspx)  haves only example with GET request..

**This is my code for get request**(*Its working*):

```
    function webProxy() {
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var request = new SP.WebRequestInfo();
    request.set_url("http://sf-spsdev07:9810/api/Holidays/GetEventDates?siteUrl=http://sf-spsdev07/sites/Test&listName=Events");
    request.set_method("GET");
    var response = SP.WebProxy.invoke(context, request);

    context.executeQueryAsync(success, fail);

    function success() {
        if (response.get_statusCode() == 200) {
            var message = jQuery("#message");

            message.text(response.get_statusCode());
            message.append(response.get_body());

        } else {
            var errorMessage = response.get_body();
            alert(errorMessage);
        }
    }

    function fail(sender, args) {
        alert("Call failed. Error: " +
            args.get_message());
    }
}
```

How to do this for Post request with body paramethers?